# Есть ли действие при закрытии своего Tab?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть самописное расширение для Unity Editor которое открывается в виде Tab. В этом расширении есть граф с данными, где у все crud операции работают.

*Но есть проблема..*

Нужно чтобы при закрытии Tab-a (Close Tab) выводилось сообщение что надо либо сохранить данные, либо нет.

[image: Выплывающее меню с необходимой мне кнопкой Close Tab]

Comment: Как дописать самописное расширение ничего про него не зная? Наверное никак.

Comment: @aepot Я участвую в небольшом проекте и мне сказали об этой проблеме. Да не сам писал эту утилиту, но захотелось помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе EditorWindow есть метод OnDestroy который вызывается при закрытии окна (в моем случае Tab-a).

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].